# How to run flask server + web socket server

Tags: python, rest, sockets

I have two pieces of blocking code, I need to run both, however running either will block the code. Both work perfectly on their own. If I could avoid using third party libraries that would be great.

```
import socket
import logging
import requests

from threading import Thread

from . import ARI_URL, ARI_USERNAME, ARI_PASSWORD, APPLICATION
from .transcription import Transcriber, MULAW

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

LISTEN_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
LISTEN_PORT = 12222

transcriber = Transcriber(language='es-ES', codec=MULAW, sample_rate=8000)

def serve(transcriber):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((LISTEN_ADDRESS, LISTEN_PORT))
    # THIS MUST RUN
    while True:
        data, _ = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        payload = data[12:]
        transcriber.push(payload)
    
    # THIS MUST RUN TOO
    app.run()

def main():
    transcriber.start()

    try:
        serve(transcriber)
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        transcriber.stop()

@app.route('/silencio', methods=['POST'])
def silencio():
    transcriber.on_silence()
    return {}
```

Comment: You have imported `Thread`, why don't you use it?

Comment: sounds interesting, how would that work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: I tried it but couldnt make it work

Comment: Use [flask-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-socketio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket server and the Flask app are both being handled in the 'serve' function.
There is an infinite loop in **sock.recvfrom**.

It will never reach the Flask app running.
There is many ways to handle this: asyncio, multiprocessing, multithreading, eventlet...
Example with asyncio:

```py
import asyncio

async def run_flask_app():
    # Async Flask run code (might need an asynchronous Flask alternative or adapter)

async def run_socket_server():
    # Your async socket server code here

# In your main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        run_flask_app(),
        run_socket_server(),
    ))
    loop.close()
```

Ot you could use [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import logging
from threading import Thread

from .transcription import Transcriber, MULAW

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

transcriber = Transcriber(language='es-ES', codec=MULAW, sample_rate=8000)

@app.route('/silencio', methods=['POST'])
def silencio():
    transcriber.on_silence()
    return {}

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    logging.info("Client connected")

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    logging.info("Client disconnected")

@socketio.on('audio_data')
def handle_audio_data(data):
    # Assuming 'data' contains the audio payload
    transcriber.push(data)

def main():
    transcriber.start()
    try:
        socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=12222)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        transcriber.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```